# Skip HTML (or javascript) in the client execution

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, safari

I would like to know, if it is possible to do the following scenario.

Go to an URL and execute step by step each HTML/Javascript section and if I don't want to execute some html or javascript part skipped it.

Maybe there are some addon for chrome or iexplorer/safari.

For example if i have the following code:

```
<html>  ---> execute 
<head.....> ---> execute 
<h1>part 1</h1> ---> execute 
<h2>part 2</h2> ---> SKIP TO H3 (don't execute in the browser)
<h3>part 3</h3> ---> execute
.
.
.
</html>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. HTML is not a language that is "executed" line-by-line; it's a page description language. That is, once the HTML code is downloaded, the browser then interprets the page and renders it. Can you provide more information about what you want to do?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to skip some lines such as javascript execution. I have 3 or 4 calls to external files and I would like to skip the execution.

Comment: Can you post some more details? Since there's no Javascript at all in your example code it's difficult to have any insight into what you're wanting to do.